# Add tableView as subview on button click outside class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableViewController` with custom Cells. The code as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section < 1) {
        static NSString *adicionaCellIdentifier = @"AdicionaCell";
        AtividadesPraticadasCustomCell *adicionaCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:adicionaCellIdentifier];
        if (!adicionaCell)
        {
            adicionaCell = [[AtividadesPraticadasCustomCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"AdicionaCell"];
        }
        adicionaCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        adicionaCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        NSLog(@"CELL1");
        return adicionaCell;
    }

    else {
        static NSString *atividadesCellIdentifier = @"AtividadesCell";
        UITableViewCell *atividadesPraticadasCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:atividadesCellIdentifier];
        if (!atividadesPraticadasCell) {
            atividadesPraticadasCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"AtividadesCell"];
        }
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_arrayAtividadesPraticadas.count);
        atividadesPraticadasCell.textLabel.text = [_arrayAtividadesPraticadas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"CELL2");


        return atividadesPraticadasCell;
    }


}
```

At the first cell, I have a `UIButton`, but it is declared in the `UITableViewCell`class I created for these cells.

I have also created a class for the `tableView` I want to add as subview of my `tableViewController`.

Now, when I use the code below for opening the subView, it doesn't work. This code is in the `UITableViewCell` class used for my custom cells.

```
- (IBAction)botaoAdicionar:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"TESTE BOTAO ADICIONAR");
    AtividadesPraticadasTableView *tableview = [[AtividadesPraticadasTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    Cadastro3TableViewController *teste = [[Cadastro3TableViewController alloc] init];
    [teste.view addSubview:tableview];

}
```

When I use the code in `ViewDidLoad`or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of my tableViewController, it works fine.

I have also tried to create a method in the `mainViewController` and calling the method from the `UIButton`, but it also didn't work. When I call the method at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, it works. I'm not sure what I am missing.

The method looks like this:

```
 - (void)abrirTableViewParaAtividadesPraticadas
 {
     AtividadesPraticadasTableView *tableview = [[AtividadesPraticadasTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
     [self.view addSubview:tableview];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button target here:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
     //init your custom cell here
     [yourCustomCell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(botaoAdicionar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

and then implement `-(IBAction)botaoAdicionar:(id)sender` method in your `UITableViewController`.

Also if you want to add a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` as subview you must do it this way:

```
[destinationVC.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];
```